# MetroFramework. Изменить BackColor или ForeColor

Tags: c#, winforms

Как у `button` изменить `BackColor` или `ForeColor`?

Я по гуглил и понял, что `UseCustomBackColor` нужно выставить значение `true`, только где? Никак не могу найти этот параметр.

Comment: Тут нужно уточнить какую именно версию `MetroFramework` вы используете?

Comment: https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework или https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui или https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui

Comment: @FoggyFinder, вот эту github.com/thielj/MetroFramework